# How to replace values in a pandas multiindex column set

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-manipulation

Given the following:

```py
dd = {}
for i in range(3):
    for j in range(3):
        key = (f"col_{i}", j)
        dd[key] = {1: 2, 3: 4}



print(pd.DataFrame.from_dict(dd))
```

Which looks as:

```
  col_0       col_1       col_2      
      0  1  2     0  1  2     0  1  2
1     2  2  2     2  2  2     2  2  2
3     4  4  4     4  4  4     4  4  4
```

I would like to use the following replacements:

```
reps = {
    "col_0": {0: "o", 1: "one", 2: "two"},
    "col_1": {0: "o2", 1: "one2", 2: "two2"},
    "col_2": {0: "o3", 1: "one3", 2: "two3"},
}
```

So that the `col_0`, `col_1`, `col_2` are unchanged, but the second level of
`0,1,2` is changed to `o, one, two`, `o2, one2, two2`, and `o3, one, two3`
respectively , giving something similar to :

```
  col_0             col_1            col_2      
      o  one  two   o2 one2 two2     o3  one3  two3
1     2  2    2      2  2    2        2    2     2
3     4  4    4      4  4    4        4    4     4
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create tuples with columns names and then for match dictionary is used `get` with second argument for default value, so if no match no replacement:

```
L = [(a, reps[a].get(b, b)) if a in reps else (a, b) for a, b in df.columns.tolist()]
df.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(L)
print (df)
  col_0         col_1           col_2          
      o one two    o2 one2 two2    o3 one3 two3
1     2   2   2     2    2    2     2    2    2
3     4   4   4     4    4    4     4    4    4
```

Test if no match outer key in `reps` dict:

```
reps = {
    "col_100": {0: "o", 1: "one", 2: "two"},
    "col_1": {0: "o2", 1: "one2", 2: "two2"},
    "col_2": {0: "o3", 1: "one3", 2: "two3"},
}

L = [(a, reps[a].get(b, b)) if a in reps else (a, b) for a, b in df.columns.tolist()]
df.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(L)
print (df)
  col_0       col_1           col_2          
      0  1  2    o2 one2 two2    o3 one3 two3
1     2  2  2     2    2    2     2    2    2
3     4  4  4     4    4    4     4    4    4
```

Test if no match inner keys:

```
reps = {
    "col_0": {100: "o", 1: "one", 20: "two"},
    "col_1": {0: "o2", 1: "one2", 2: "two2"},
    "col_2": {0: "o3", 1: "one3", 2: "two3"},
}

L = [(a, reps[a].get(b, b)) if a in reps else (a, b) for a, b in df.columns.tolist()]
df.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(L)
print (df)
  col_0        col_1           col_2          
      0 one  2    o2 one2 two2    o3 one3 two3
1     2   2  2     2    2    2     2    2    2
3     4   4  4     4    4    4     4    4    4
```